# How to send json schema validation for mutual dependency field to ajv npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Thanks! I tried many ways to resolve it but I am unable to resolve it.
Here is the sample payload except for caseId every field is an optional field :

```
{
"CaseId": "xxxxxxxx",
"OpsrampStatus":"New",
"Reference": [
  {
    "Type": "GDDC Incident Number",
    "ReferenceNumber": "INC-xxx"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Opsramp Incident Number",
    "ReferenceNumber": "INC-xxx"
  }
]  }
```

so here **OpsrampStatus** is Mandatary field when the **Reference** array contains **Type** field as *Opsramp Incident Number*

Pass Case:

1.

```
{
"CaseId": "xxxxxxxx",
"Reference": [
  {
    "Type": "GDDC Incident Number",
    "ReferenceNumber": "INC-xxx"
  },
  
]}
```

2. 

```
`{
    "CaseId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "OpsrampStatus":"New",
    "Reference": [
      {
        "Type": "Opsramp Incident Number",
        "ReferenceNumber": "INC-xxx"
      }
    ]  }
`
```

Failed Case:

1.
`

```
{
    "CaseId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Reference": [
      {
        "Type": "Opsramp Incident Number",
        "ReferenceNumber": "INC-xxx"
      }
    ]  }
```

`
2.

```
`{
    "CaseId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "OpsrampStatus":"New",
   }
`
```

Here is the schema I tried

Comment: I didn't get your point. Why you didn't use scheme validation libraries like Yup and joy?

Comment: I am using ajv module